# Como funciona a herança no PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, herança

Como funciona a herança no PostgreSQL? É uma boa prática no âmbito de banco de dados relacionais? Como utilizá-la?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não funciona. Na prática ela está implementada pela metade e é muito raro ser útil para alguma coisa, ainda que a parte funcional não seja especialmente problemática.

De forma geral não é uma "boa prática" tentar reproduzir o modelo orientado a objeto em um banco de dados relacional. Dá mais trabalho fazer certo do que fazer do jeito tradicional. Talvez fosse diferente se tudo estivesse feito perfeitamente, mas abandonaram porque não era algo realmente tão útil e jamais ficaria tão bom quanto as pessoas esperam.

Então nem vou tentar explicar o funcionamento, ninguém em sã consciência usa, pelo menos como herança de verdade. Há o uso para particionamento, mas é usar o mecanismo de herança para não fazer herança, e sim suprir uma outra necessidade.

Quando você tem tabelas diversas com a mesma estrutura que precisam ser agrupadas de alguma forma a herança pode ser usada, mas note que isto não é herança de fato como conhecemos em orientação a objeto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 pelo "ninguém são usa" e pela sinceridade.