# Como instanciar uma variável (para ser primary key) do construtor dentro da tabela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

A pergunta está mal formulada, porém o problema é o seguinte.
Estou trabalhando com **BDOR** no **PostgreSql**. Criei duas Types e estou agregando-as na Type **animal**.
Logo após, usei Herança e criei a tabela **mamiferos** do tipo animal.
Só que quero usar o atributo **nome** dentro da type **dono_ty** como **primary key**. Quero usar primary key, pois uma mesma pessoa (mesmo cpf) pode cadastrar nas tabelas mamiferos, aves e repteis (vou criar mais duas), daí eu gostaria de fazer um **select** dessas informações. Como eu poderia resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja tentei também as seguintes maneiras:

> CREATE TABLE mamiferos OF animal(cpf primary key);
>   CREATE TABLE mamiferos OF animal(dono.cpf primary key);

Comment: DÊ uma lida nisso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192911/101

Comment: Eu diria que seria `CREATE TABLE mamiferos OF animal(dono.cpf primary key);`, mas me parece estranho que você queira que cpf seja uma primary key pelo que você diz na introdução "pois uma mesma pessoa (mesmo cpf) pode cadastrar nas tabelas mamiferos, aves e repteis (vou criar mais duas)".

Answer (score 0):

Heranças são bonitas na teoria, mas são um inferno na prática. Uma excelente alternativa é o uso de uma `coluna discriminadora`, que na verdade é uma chave estrangeira que aponta para o tipo daquele animal.

Veja como sua ideia pode ser estruturada de outra forma:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_porte (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  descricao TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tb_tipo_animal (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  descricao TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tb_dono (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nome TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tb_animal (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  nome TEXT,
  especie TEXT,
  id_porte INTEGER REFERENCES tb_porte (id),
  id_dono INTEGER REFERENCES tb_dono (id),
  id_tipo INTEGER REFERENCES tb_tipo_animal (id), -- Coluna Discriminadora
  dt_consulta DATE,
  diagnostico TEXT
);
```

Populando tabelas:

```
-- PORTE DO ANIMAL
INSERT INTO tb_porte (id, descricao) VALUES ( 1, 'PEQUENO');
INSERT INTO tb_porte (id, descricao) VALUES ( 2, 'MEDIO');
INSERT INTO tb_porte (id, descricao) VALUES ( 3, 'GRANDE');

-- TIPO DO ANIMAL
INSERT INTO tb_tipo_animal (id, descricao) VALUES ( 1, 'MAMIFERO');
INSERT INTO tb_tipo_animal (id, descricao) VALUES ( 2, 'AVE');
INSERT INTO tb_tipo_animal (id, descricao) VALUES ( 3, 'REPTIL');

-- DONOS
INSERT INTO tb_dono (id, nome) VALUES ( 1, 'WALT DISNEY');
INSERT INTO tb_dono (id, nome) VALUES ( 2, 'SUPER MARIO');
INSERT INTO tb_dono (id, nome) VALUES ( 3, 'WALTER LANTZ');
INSERT INTO tb_dono (id, nome) VALUES ( 4, 'CEBOLINHA');

-- ANIMAIS
INSERT INTO tb_animal ( nome, especie, id_dono, id_tipo, id_porte ) VALUES ('MICKEY',      'RATO',        1, 1, 2 );
INSERT INTO tb_animal ( nome, especie, id_dono, id_tipo, id_porte ) VALUES ('PATETA',      'CACHORRO',    1, 1, 2 );
INSERT INTO tb_animal ( nome, especie, id_dono, id_tipo, id_porte ) VALUES ('DONALD',      'PATO',        1, 2, 2 );
INSERT INTO tb_animal ( nome, especie, id_dono, id_tipo, id_porte ) VALUES ('PICA-PAU',    'PASSARO',     3, 2, 1 );
INSERT INTO tb_animal ( nome, especie, id_dono, id_tipo, id_porte ) VALUES ('WALLY GATOR', 'JACARE',      3, 3, 3 );
INSERT INTO tb_animal ( nome, especie, id_dono, id_tipo, id_porte ) VALUES ('YOSHI',       'DINOSSAURO',  2, 3, 3 );
INSERT INTO tb_animal ( nome, especie, id_dono, id_tipo, id_porte ) VALUES ('BIDU',        'CACHORRO',    4, 1, 1 );
```

Consulta Exemplo:

```
SELECT
  a.nome AS no_animal,
  d.nome AS no_dono,
  a.especie AS ds_especie,
  t.descricao AS no_tipo,
  p.descricao AS ds_porte
FROM
  tb_animal AS a
LEFT JOIN
  tb_dono AS d ON (d.id = a.id_dono)
LEFT JOIN
  tb_tipo_animal AS t ON (t.id = a.id_tipo)
LEFT JOIN
  tb_porte AS p ON (p.id = a.id_porte)
```

Saída:

```
|   no_animal |      no_dono | ds_especie |  no_tipo | ds_porte |
|-------------|--------------|------------|----------|----------|
|      MICKEY |  WALT DISNEY |       RATO | MAMIFERO |    MEDIO |
|      PATETA |  WALT DISNEY |   CACHORRO | MAMIFERO |    MEDIO |
|      DONALD |  WALT DISNEY |       PATO |      AVE |    MEDIO |
|    PICA-PAU | WALTER LANTZ |    PASSARO |      AVE |  PEQUENO |
| WALLY GATOR | WALTER LANTZ |     JACARE |   REPTIL |   GRANDE |
|       YOSHI |  SUPER MARIO | DINOSSAURO |   REPTIL |   GRANDE |
|        BIDU |    CEBOLINHA |   CACHORRO | MAMIFERO |  PEQUENO |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ae24e/7)

Referencia: [Herança em banco de dados relacionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35054/heran%C3%A7a-em-banco-de-dados-relacionais)